# make json array from mysql data using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take some data from my mysql database, and pass it to a json array, so that I can use it in my android application.

But so far I'm having trouble getting any data from the mysql db, when i run my php code in the browser to check output, i get a blank screen. Can someone help ?

CODE:

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","testUser","root","EasyFridge") or die("error". mysqli_error($connection));
$sql = "select * from product";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql); 
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $emparray[] = array("product" => $row);
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Try using `mysqli_connect_error()` instead of `mysqli_error($connection)`

Comment: The problem is not the connection, but the json array.. I can't seem to get all rows from the db in the array..

Comment: check for any php errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Returns a blank webside, no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at error log of PHP. It's very likely that the script exceeded max memory available. If so, you may try following actions:

- Increase max memory in php.ini file by setting `memory_limit` parameter or call in your code `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`;
- Break your data into pages with more appropriate count of objects returned.

Comment: But what help is that, if i do not know how to fix it ?

Comment: @Lasse, I've updated my answer with possible solutions of exceeding memory limit problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it did unfurtunetly not solve my problem, still a blank page... But thanks anyway

Comment: Is there any error logs entries related to the script execution?

Comment: That's strange. I would suggest you try to execute the script in the shell (to check whether it is HTTP server closing connection or it's PHP fault), check number of products which was returned by the query, check products themselves (if you can output just an array of them), and still keep looking at error logs of PHP and HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Found the error, was missing a charset decoding statement, so just added:

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","testUser","root", "EasyFridge") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
    mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8"); //ADDED THIS LINE!! 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $returnarray = array();
    //create an array
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {
                //$emparray[] = $row[];
                $emparray['id'] = $row['id'];
                $emparray['name'] = $row['name'];
                $emparray['placement_date'] = $row['placement_date'];
                $emparray['removal_date'] = $row['removal_date'];
                $emparray['type'] = $row['type'];

                array_push($returnarray, $emparray);
                }
                //var_dump($returnarray);
                echo json_encode($returnarray);
    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```